# How to setup turtlebot3 on ROS Noetic

Tags: ros, turtlebot, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

Does anyone know how to setup a turtlebot3 on ROS Noetic? I've trying to follow along the tutorials on this link by exchanging kinetic with noetic:

https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/pc_setup/

but as of right now, I haven't been able to be much successful.

I'm using ROS Noetic on Ubuntu 20
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354131/how-to-setup-turtlebot3-on-ros-noetic/) by [anonymous53443](https://answers.ros.org/users/53443/anonymous53443/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2020-06-05

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robur](https://answers.ros.org/users/25824/robur/) on 2020-06-12**:
I also have this problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This tutorial is a lot better for setting up turtlebot3 siimulation on ROS Noetic:

https://automaticaddison.com/how-to-launch-the-turtlebot3-simulation-with-ros/

Long story short, messages, the robot, and simulated worlds all need to be pulled from repositories individually.  Also there is an update needed for ~/.bashrc

Hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [tommylwalker](https://answers.ros.org/users/56918/tommylwalker/) with karma: 56 on 2020-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3